# Returning an error status in Haskell and Yesod

Tags: haskell, http-status-codes, yesod

I am a Haskell newbie.

I am trying to write a small [Webdav](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) server using the [Yesod Framework](http://www.yesodweb.com/) and modelled after the `WebdavServlet` in the Apache Tomcat 7 source code. I have run into a problem returning an error from one of my functions.

My webdav service should return either XML or JSON, depending on the value of the `Accept` header sent in by the caller. I defined a data type called `RepXmlJson`:

```
import Yesod

data RepXmlJson = RepXmlJson RepXml RepJson

instance HasReps RepXmlJson where
  chooseRep (RepXmlJson (RepXml xml) (RepJson json)) = chooseRep
    [ (typeXml, xml)
    , (typeJson, json)
    ]
```

I am using this data type as the return value of my services, specifically the `lockWebdavR` function. I am trying to return a status 423 (locked) if a resource is currently locked. My code looks like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Map        as M
import qualified Data.Text       as T
import qualified Network.Wai     as W

mkYesodSub "Webdav" [] [parseRoutes|
  / WebdavR COPY DELETE LOCK MKCOL MOVE OPTIONS PROPFIND PROPPATCH PUT UNLOCK
|]

type WebdavHandler yesod = GHandler Webdav yesod

webdavLocked423 :: Status
webdavLocked423 = Status 423 "Locked"

isLockedRequest :: Yesod master => Request -> WebdavHandler master Bool
-- isLockedRequest definition omitted for brevity

lockWebdavR :: Yesod master => WebdavHandler master RepXmlJson
lockWebdavR = do
  request <- getRequest
  locked <- isLockedRequest request
  if locked
    then return $
      W.responseLBS webdavLocked423 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] ""
    else return undefined
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Webdav.hs:94:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `RepXmlJson'
                with actual type `W.Response'
    Expected type: GHandler Webdav master RepXmlJson
      Actual type: GHandler Webdav master W.Response
    In the expression:
      return
      $ W.responseLBS webdavLocked423 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] ""
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if locked then
          return
          $ W.responseLBS webdavLocked423 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] ""
      else
          return undefined
```

I searched through the book ["Developing Web Applications with Haskell and Yesod"](http://www.yesodweb.com/book), but cannot find an example of returning an error of the proper type (`Rep...`).

How do I create a `RepXmlJson` with the correct error status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal completion of a handler always results in a 200 status code. To override that, you have to send a response some other way. In your case, you could try `sendResponseStatus`. Other possibilities would be `sendWaiResponse` and `redirectWith`, though I doubt the latter will be useful.

Comment: I changed the return value to `sendResponseStatus webdavLocked423 $ RepXmlJson (RepXml "") (RepJson "")` and it compiles. Thanks. BTW, nice book.

Comment: I use `invalidArgs ["Could not parse refs"]` to respond with a 400 error.  But dont understand what happens to my message...